# SQL how to select unique one-to-one pairings

Tags: mysql, sql

*edited to make clearer - many apologies for the confusion of the original example*

I have the following table structure representing married couples:

```
id | Person | Spouse
______________________
1  | Mary   | John
2  | John   | Mary
3  | Katy   | Bob
4  | Bob    | Katy
5  | Mary   | John
6  | John   | Mary
```

In this example Mary is married to John, Katy to Bob and a **different** Mary is married to a different John.

How can I retrieve these pairs of married couples?

I have got close with this:

```
SELECT 
  p.id id1,
  q.id id2
FROM 
  people p 
  INNER JOIN people q ON
    p.person = q.spouse AND 
    q.person = p.spouse AND 
    p.id < q.id
ORDER BY p.id
```

However this returns:

```
1 | 2 (1st Mary & 1st John)
1 | 6 (1st Mary & 2nd John) *problem*
2 | 5 (1st John & 2nd Mary) *problem*
3 | 4 (Katy & Bob)
5 | 6 (2nd Mary & 2nd John)
```

How can I make sure the 1st Mary and 1st John are only married once (i.e. remove the problem rows above)?

Many thanks

Here's the SQL to create the example:

```
CREATE TABLE people
    (`id` int, `person` varchar(7), `spouse` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO people
    (`id`, `person`, `spouse`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Mary', 'John'),
    (2, 'John', 'Mary'),
    (3, 'Katy', 'Bob'),
    (4, 'Bob', 'Katy'),
    (5, 'Mary', 'John'),
    (6, 'John', 'Mary')
;

SELECT 
  p.id id1,
  q.id id2
FROM 
  people p 
  INNER JOIN people q ON
    p.person = q.spouse AND 
    q.person = p.spouse AND 
    p.id < q.id
ORDER BY p.id
;
```

Comment: Did you alias your columns in your real query? I get the correct result if I do: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/182cf/2

Comment: The query seems correct. A different problem will appear when you'll have 2 (different) Mary, each married to a (different) John. Then this query will show 4 marriages. And nothing will save you there, unless you provide a means to identify persons (as CBroe suggests in his answer).

Comment: My sincere apologies - in simplifying my example I accidentally left out exactly what you ypercube have just highlighted:When I have two "Mary"s, each married to a different "John", I get double the marriages reported. It's exactly this problem I'm trying to tackle.

Comment: And if you have 3 (marriages of Mary to John), you'll get 9 in the results :)

Comment: To be more specific: When I have two "Mary"s, each married to a different "John", I get the first Mary is married to both Johns.

Comment: Lets say we write a query and solve your problem. There are 2 solutions for this instance of data: `(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)` and `(1,6) (3,4) (2,5)` Should any of the 2 be considered as correct?

Comment: Yes exactly - either are perfectly valid. Is it possible to write something that can produce one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id1,
  q.id AS id2
FROM
  people AS p 
  JOIN people AS q ON
    p.person = q.spouse AND 
    q.person = p.spouse AND 
    p.id < q.id
  JOIN (SELECT 
          p.id, COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM 
          people AS p 
          INNER JOIN people AS p2 ON
            p.person = p2.person AND 
            p.spouse = p2.spouse AND 
            p.id >= p2.id
        GROUP BY p.id
       ) AS x ON
    x.id = p.id
  JOIN (SELECT 
          p.id, COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM 
          people AS p 
          INNER JOIN people AS p2 ON
            p.person = p2.person AND 
            p.spouse = p2.spouse AND 
            p.id >= p2.id
        GROUP BY p.id
       ) AS y ON
    y.id = q.id AND
    y.rank = x.rank ;
```

And another one:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS id1,
  q.id AS id2
FROM
  people AS p 
  JOIN people AS q ON
    p.person = q.spouse AND 
    q.person = p.spouse
  JOIN people AS p2 ON
    p.person = p2.person AND 
    p.spouse = p2.spouse AND 
    p.id >= p2.id
  JOIN people AS q2 ON
    q.person = q2.person AND 
    q.spouse = q2.spouse AND 
    q.id >= q2.id
WHERE 
    p.id < q.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id, q.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT p2.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT q2.id) ;
```

Both tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/842e9/2)**

It would be much simpler, if only MySQL had window functions (like almost all other DBMS have). Tested at [Postgres fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7a937/1):

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT
        id, person, spouse, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY person, spouse 
                           ORDER BY id )
           AS rn
    FROM
        people
  ) 
SELECT
    p.id AS id1,
    q.id AS id2 
FROM
  cte AS p
  JOIN cte AS q ON
    p.person = q.spouse AND 
    q.person = p.spouse AND
    p.rn = q.rn AND
    p.id < q.id ;
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you so much indeed ypercube. I didn't realise it would be so involved (!)

Comment: Absolutely awesome (re the 2nd one). To a newbie like myself the 2nd one seems more efficient (fewer nested queries) - is that right?

Comment: It probably is. But with big tables, neither of them would be very efficient. In any case, composite indexes on `(person, spouse, id)` and on `(spouse, person, id)` will be needed I think.

Comment: Hugely appreciated, this is really great, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

> In this example Mary is married to John, Katy to Bob and a different Mary is married to Richard.

**Nothing** in your show data structures allows to differentiate between those two “Marys”, because there *is* no difference between them.

Both are just the text literal `Mary`. If you want to differentiate between different people that might have the same name, then you need another criterion, and a *unique* one at that. (F.e. the *id* of the database records for each individual person.)

Comment: but the join `ON` condition provides the uniqueness needed by matching person1 and person2 on _both_ sides of the join.

Comment: Yes, apologies - please see my edited post above which hopefully makes the question clearer, many thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I have the unique identifier of the *person* but not that of his/her spouse. I need to find the matching id of the spouse whilst allowing each person to be married only once.

Comment: Why do you safe _names_ in your table then instead of ids?

Comment: I'm provided only with the list of Persons and their Spouses, not with ids. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your database stricture is wrong.

People like Mary, John, etc. do not have identity.

Some heuristic query might help, but it is not a reliable solution.

So, please, improve you data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Not very elegant, but works:

```
SELECT p.id, q.id
FROM people p
INNER JOIN people q ON
p.person1 = q.person2 and 
q.person1 = p.person1
```

which in fact uses the existance of an inverted row as a selector

Comment: My sincere apologies - in simplifying my example I accidentally left out exactly what ypercube has just highlighted above: When I have two "Mary"s, each married to a different "John", I get the first Mary is married to both Johns. It's this problem I'm trying to tackle.

Answer (score -1):

There's lots of ways of doing it, however one of the most important reasons for using a database is that it holds *lots* of data - and there should rarely be times when you ever write a query which retrieves *lots* of data. Except in very unusual circumstances, and for homework assignments, the results should be filtered according to some criteria. Hence the most appropriate solution depends on what other stuff you add to the query later.

But here's a couple of examples of how to get the unique pairs:

```
SELECT a, b, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
(SELECT id
, IF (person>=spouse, person, spouse) as a
, IF (person>=spouse, spouse, person) as b
FROM yourtable ) AS pairs
GROUP BY a,b;

SELECT id, person, spouse
FROM yourtable s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable s2
    WHERE s2.id>s1.id
    AND s1.person=s2.spouse
    AND s1.spouse=S2.person);
```

(there are several other solutions).

Comment: Thanks but the first example gives me Katy Katy 3,4 | Mary Mary 1,6,2,5. The second example is closer as it gives 4 Bob Katy | 6 John Mary. But neither example give what I'm after namely 1 2 | 3 4 | 5 6

Comment: Yes - I was in a bit of a hurry and didn't reverse the entries in the second if statement (now fixed) - wasn't this obvious? The expected output you've cited in your comment here does not match the expected output in your original question.

Comment: ypercube's 3 solutions above are doing the correct thing to solve the original question (see top). Thanks in any case.